# Am I using the right version of pg_routing

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting, debian

I am using PostgreSQL 13 (PostgreSQL 13.10 (Debian 13.10-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit) and when I execute

```
SELECT pgr_full_version();
```

I get the following result

> (3.5.0,Release,2023/03/08,pgrouting-3.5.0,Linux,""PostgreSQL 15.2
> (Debian 15.2-2.pgdg110+1)"",GNU-10.2.1,1.74.0,unknown)

I searched pgRouting code and it seems that the PostgreSQL version is determined by cmake at build time using `find_package(PostgreSQL)`

Despite the fact that I installed pg_routing with `apt-get install postgresql-13-pgrouting`. Should I disregard the version returned by `pgr_full_version`?

I ask this question because I encounter random hangs when using `pgr_ksp`